# Custom headers for each pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using Meteor Slides plugin for showing header in slideshow.Now what i need is to show this header on only home page and show different header images in different pages. I got a plugin called "WP Display header" for displaying different header images for different pages.But the slideshow header along with two custom headers with same image which i set using WP Display Header plugin. How can solve this problem and show the slideshow on the homepage only and different headers in different pages? Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got answer for it. I have changed the code to add meteor slides plugin in functions.php to show the slideshow just in the homepage.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) {
if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { 
     meteor_slideshow(); 
}
} ?>
```

After that i used a plug called [WP display header](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-display-header/) to set header image for each page